# How to retrieve Facebook friendlist and save it to parse?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am making an app that utilizes Facebook friendlist of the user. I have an array type column on my parse backend named `fbFriendsList`. After looking around, So far I have this:

```
//my permission array
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me",@"email", @"user_friends"];
//My fb request for friends after verifying that user is logging in the first time    
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {

                            NSArray *friendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                            //fbFriendIds is a Mutable array i have declared
                            fbFriendIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:friendObjects.count];
                            // Create a list of friends' Facebook IDs
                            for (NSDictionary *friendObject in friendObjects) {
                                [fbFriendIds addObject:[friendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
                            }

                        }
                    }];
```

By doing that, I didn't receive any friends in the list. So I tried this one:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
                [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                                              NSError *error) {
                    friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
                    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
                        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
                    }
                }];
```

But I still didn't get the friends. Later in a function I am saving the array to `PFUser` like this

```
user[@"fbFriendsList"] = friends;


 [user saveInBackground];
```

But this returns `Found: 0`. Why aren't these methods retrieving friends list? How can I do it and save it to my parse backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since April 2014, you only get those users who authorized your App too, take a look at the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Users who did not authorized your App have no possibility to know if you store their data, so it makes sense if you think about privacy.

The only way to get all friends nowadays is to use [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2) for inviting users to your App and [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) for tagging users. But in your case, there is no way to get all of them.

Comment: But I have another apps code. It was built like few months ago and it is still working fine using the same methods.

Comment: read the changelog. older apps (created before end of april 2014) can still use v1.0, which returns all friends until april 2015.

Comment: Alright can you explain this part "Invites have the same behavior as Requests, and will direct recipients to one of the following places:

Your app on Facebook Canvas.
Your native app on iOS or Android, if installed.
The Apple App Store or Google Play, if not installed."? I can use this stuff to add friends on a iOS app right? Even if i am not using fb canvas

Comment: no, this is what you need to read for external websites/apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: and you don´t want to invite friends, you want to store friends. you can´t do that anymore.