# Why is facebook returning the friendlist 0 in iOS? How to retrieve fb friendlist and store it to parse?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Please see this previous discussion for building the context. [How to retrieve Facebook friendlist and save it to parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700052/how-to-retrieve-fb-friendlist-and-save-it-to-parse).
As that guy pointed out it's not possible any longer to retrieve friendlists, I tried retrieving it by using the older sdk. That sdk is working fine with my other app. But i still can't retrieve fb friendlist. I tried this method too, other than the two mentioned in the above stated question:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:
                 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphUser> friends, NSError *error)
                 {}];
```

But it's still no bueno. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it? How can i retrieve the fb friendlist and store it to parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful with "friendlist" and "friends", those are two different things. Although, i am pretty sure you don´t want to get the "friendlists", because those are just the lists without the friends in there.

Anyway, using an old SDK does not mean you can get all friends, the only way to still get all friends is by using an App created before end of April 2014 (with any SDK). And that solution only works until end of April 2015, of course.

Comment: That's disappointing. Thanks again man. and on the other hands, i want to keep a list of like fb ids of someone's friends so for that i'd use 'friends'?

Comment: No i don't want to get their likes. I just want to know who's friend with whom so that they can find their friends when they join my app.

Comment: /me/friends is what you need then

Comment: Hey I got a fb app created before April 2014. it's still the same. no friends retrieved. What should i do?

Comment: then it was either inactive before april 2014 (those apps will not be able to use v1.0 either), or you are using a newer sdk with a newer api tag. try it in the graph api explorer with that old app, to check it out.

Comment: that being said, i suggest not wasting time on this at all, as it will stop working after april 2015.