# How to get facebook friend list using PFFacebookUtilsV4 ios + Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I am using "Login with Facebook" using PFFacebookUtilsV4 and I want to get facebook friends using lastest parse version.

I can able to get facebook friends using old parse but I need facebook friends using newer version of [parse.com](/questions/tagged/parse.com) sdk

When I trying to fetch Facebook friend then I got alert message "Please log into this app again to reconnect your facebook account" and click "OK" button get the Facebook Friends.

How to remove "Please log into this app again to reconnect your facebook account" alert from facebook?

Comment: Relevant: [How to retrieve list of Facebook friends and save it to Parse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700052/how-to-retrieve-facebook-friendlist-and-save-it-to-parse), and [Facebook friendlist returning 0. How to fetch it and save it to Parse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777634/why-is-facebook-returning-the-friendlist-0-in-ios-how-to-retrieve-fb-friendlist)

Comment: FBRequestConnection is not working in new parse sdk

Comment: That's why I said relevant, didn't vote to close this as dupe. Anyways its a method of FB sdk, not parse. But what's good for the goose......

Comment: I can successfully "login with facebook" using parse and I am trying fetch facebook friend using `FBSDKGraphRequest` then session is not match